# How to perform an argparse subparse for [-A[-b value]] in Python

Tags: python, argparse, subparsers

I want to recreate [-A [-b value]] where in command would look like this:

> test.py -A -b 123

Seems really simple but I can't get it right. My latest attempt has been:

```
byte = subparser.add_parser("-A")
byte.add_argument("-b", type=int)
```

Comment: `add_parser` should probably return an error if you attempt to use an option name as an argument.

Comment: it does, the code above returns, error: invalid choice: '123' (choose from '-A')

Comment: No, I mean the call to `add_parser` itself, not when you call `parse_args()`, because such a subcommand appears to be buggy, at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the `add_parser` command accepts '-A', the parser cannot use it. Look at the help:

```
usage: ipython3 [-h] {-A} ...

positional arguments:
  {-A}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

A subparser is really a special kind of `positional` argument. To the main parser, you have effectively defined

```
add_argument('cmd', choices=['-A'])
```

But to the parsing code, '-A' looks like an `optional's` flag, as though you had defined

```
add_argument('-A')
```

The error:

```
error: argument cmd: invalid choice: '123' (choose from '-A')
```

means that it has skipped over the `-A` and `-b` (which aren't defined for the main parser), and tried to parse '123' as the first positional.  But it isn't in the list of valid choices.

So to use subparsers, you need specify 'A' as the subparser, not '-A'.

Comment: Gotcha, I have tried this way also before posting with error, unrecognized arguments -B -s. And as you and cheapner (comments above) have mentioned, I do the unorthodox declaration of -A, -t, etc. within " " but out of all videos/tutorials I have yet to see a formal declaration for input >> test.py -a 123 -t ph

Comment: Like you said add_argument does allow "-A", with subparser, however, this won't cut it